# Continuous Probability and Central Limit Theorem -- Approximating sum of coin tosses distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I ran into a problem I know I have to use central limit theorem and continuous probability for, but I'm not sure how to really apply those. Would appreciate some guidance :))

> Assume there are 1 through k people with coins. Person i's coin has
> sides i and -i. They toss their coins n times and sum the outputs into
> a number $X_i$. For a large n, what is the distribution of $(X_1 + ... +
> > X_k)/\sqrt{n}$ approximately equal?

Comment: It might be worth finding the variance of the sum and then seeing if one of the generalisations of the central limit theorem can be used.  But I suspect that $(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/\sqrt{n^3}$ might be more interesting

Comment: I agree. I'm getting that $\frac{X_1+\dots +X_n}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges in probability to a $N(0,1/3)$ distribution.

Comment: Is the distinction between $k$ and $n$ supposed to be there or is that a typo? If they are the same then not even a generalization of CLT really applies because the variance of the ratio is growing, since the variance of the numerator is on the order of $n^3$ which can't be compensated by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator. It would need a factor of $n^{3/2}$ in the denominator to be compensated.

Comment: @Ian I was confused too, but I'm pretty sure the distinction is supposed to be there: $k$ is fixed and $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @Ian yep, they are different,  there are k people and each toss their coins n times.

Comment: @Henry I shall try that! This is just with the generic formula for variance right?

Comment: when calculating variance of Xn, should we be breaking that down to the var(Xi) where Xi = Bobi's toss and then down to var(Ti) where Ti = toss i and sum everything all together?

Comment: @Melanie - I may have originally misread the question wrong thinking $k=n$.  Finding the variance helps, and you can apply the CLT by breaking the sum down and then putting it back together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the result of person $i$'s $j$th toss $Y_{i,j}$ which has mean $0$ and variance $i^2$.

Now let $Z_j = Y_{1,j}+\cdots + Y_{k,j}$, which will have mean $0$ and variance $\frac16 k(k+1)(2k+1)$.

Applying the central limit theorem to $Z_j$, we get that $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}(Z_1+ \cdots + Z_{n})$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N\left(0, \frac16 k(k+1)(2k+1)\right)$.

Since  $Z_1+ \cdots + Z_{n} = X_1+\cdots +X_k$, you get that $\frac{X_1+\cdots +X_k}{\sqrt{n}}$ also converges in distribution to $\mathcal N\left(0, \frac16 k(k+1)(2k+1)\right)$.

Comment: thank you! do you mind explaining how you got those variances though? I got a little lost with that

Comment: @Melanie Which one is causing you difficulty?

Comment: The variance on $Z_j$ which is $\mathcal N\left(0, \frac16 k(k+1)(2k+1)\right)$. also, how is that the standard deviation of the normal distribution we converge to? what happened to the $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: $\sum \limits_{i=1}^k i^2= \frac16 k(k+1)(2k+1)$.  It is a variance rather than a standard deviation, so you might want to consider its square root

Comment: $n$ cannot be in the limit as the limit is taken as $n \to \infty$.  But you need the $\sqrt{n}$ to scale the sum  to keep its variance positive, finite and constant for this application of the central limit theorem

Comment: oh okay, thank you! and would you also be able to explain where the $i^2$ came from?

Comment: " Person $i$'s coin has sides $i$ and $-i$" so the variance is $\frac12(i-0)^2+\frac12(-i-0)^2=i^2$